# Converting an int array of Drawable images to a string array of their filenames

Tags: android, arrays, loops, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to save an array of Drawables as Int (which is later used to set `setImageResource`)

There's some logic I need to perform on `SharedPreferences` that **requires** me to get the actual filename, NOT the `Int` representation of the drawable.

**My code is the following:**

```
val imagesFromSaved = PrefsContext(context).savedLocations
```

`imagesFromSaved` prints the following:

```
[2131135903, 2131165414, 2134135800, 2131765348]
```

I need to be able to print the actual filename. Like this.

```
["image_one", "image_two", "image_three", "image_four"]
```

The closest I got was using `getString` with one single `Int`. But I'm not sure how to iterate over all the items in the array to convert everything to the string representation.

```
val test = context.resources.getString(2131135903)
```

Prints:   `res/drawable-nodpi-v4/image_one.webp`

**How can I iterate over my `SharedPreferences` to generate an array of Drawable filenames, instead of the Int representation of the resource?**

Comment: You want the `resources.getResourceEntryName()` function instead.

Comment: @MikeM. Would I just use a for loop to create the new array of Strings from imagesFromSaved?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the loop was part of the unknown. Sergey's got a proper example in their answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through int array and convert them to strings you can use [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) function:

```
val imagesFromSaved = PrefsContext(context).savedLocations
val imagesNames: List<String> = imagesFromSaved.map {
    context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(it)
}
```

`map` transforms the list of objects to a list of objects of another type.
The resulting `imagesNames` should contain the names of images.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you should do as follows:

- firstly, save the str which is your description fileName
- Then  get the fileName from sp
- In the end, you have to use the str to generate the drawable id

```
//get the R.draw.fileName,it result is fileName
val fileName = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.arrow_back)

// then use SharedPreferences get the  str, To generate ID
val id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

// then use the id in imageView
imegeView.setImageResource(id)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Looks like I just need to simply convert my array of Int to a string array using the getResourceEntryName function. Trying to work on that now.